If $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are abelian categories, and $F:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ is fully faithful, is $F$ exact?
If $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are two abelian categories, and $F:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ is a fully faithful functor, can we conclude that $F$ is an exact functor?
By default, $F$ is an additive functor.
I suspect there exists a counterexample, but I have not identified one yet.

The functor $F$ might not even be additive, and even if it is, it might not preserve kernels or cokernels.

@Geoffrey Trang Thank you. By default, $F$ is an additive functor.

For a possible counterexample, take $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ to be the sheaves and presheaves of abelian groups respectively (on some topological space) and $F$ to be the inclusion functor.

Okay, let me think about it.

Maybe for a more concrete counterexample, it might work to take the inclusion of the category of cartesian squares of abelian groups into the category of commutative squares of abelian groups?  (That being inspired by taking the special case of Geoffrey Trang's comment where the topological space is $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ for some algebraically complete field $k$.)

@DanielSchepler Your counterexample is not an instance of my suggestion to consider sheaves and presheaves on any topological space. While the category of commutative squares is obviously the category of presheaves on a two-point discrete space $X={0,1}$, a sheaf $F$ must map the empty set to the trivial abelian group (in addition to having $F(X)$ as the pullback $F({0}) \times_{F(\emptyset)} F({1})$).

@GeoffreyTrang My counterexample was inspired by the fact that a quasicoherent sheaf of modules on $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is determined by the cartesian square of sections over the whole space, $D_+(x)$, $D_+(y)$, and $D_+(x) \cap D_+(y)$.  (Of course, that does involve a square of a $k[x,y] / \langle xy - 1 \rangle$-module, a $k[x]$-module, a $k[y]$-module, and a $k$-module; but it seems that simplifying that to "quasicoherent sheaves vs. presheaves of abelian groups" works.)

I guess you could also view my example as coming from the Grothendieck site of the commutative square diagram with the two maps to the lower right being a covering.  So not quite a topological space, but close enough.

For a counterexample, consider the categories $\mathcal{C} := \mathsf{Ab}^c$ and $\mathcal{D} := \mathsf{Ab}^s$, where $c$ is the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@. \cdot \\
@. @VVV \\
\cdot @>>> \cdot
\end{CD}
and $s$ is the commutative square diagram
\begin{CD}
\cdot @>>> \cdot \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\cdot @>>> \cdot
\end{CD}
We then have a "cartesian square completion" functor $F$ which takes the object of $\mathcal{C}$
\begin{CD}
@. A \\
@. @VVV \\
B @>>> C
\end{CD}
to the object of $\mathcal{D}$
\begin{CD}
A \times_C B @>>> A \\
@VVV @VVV \\
B @>>> C
\end{CD}
and where it should be straightforward to fill in the action of $F$ on morphisms using the universal property of the fibered product.
I will leave it as an exercise to show that $F$ is a fully faithful functor.  It also happens that $F$ is left exact.  However, $F$ is not right exact: for example, consider the morphism from
\begin{CD}
@. \mathbb{Z} \\
@. @V i_1 VV \\
\mathbb{Z} @> i_2 >> \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}
\end{CD}
to
\begin{CD}
@. \mathbb{Z} \\
@. @V \operatorname{id} VV \\
\mathbb{Z} @> \operatorname{id} >> \mathbb{Z}
\end{CD}
which acts as the identity on the $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ components, and as the sum map on the $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ component.  This morphism is clearly an epimorphism in $\mathcal{C}$.  However, the image under $F$ has top-left component $0 \to \mathbb{Z}$, so the image under $F$ is not an epimorphism.

Hmm, now I'm curious what the right derived functors of $F$ are.  If the analogy with quasicoherent sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is any indication, one might expect $R^i F$ to vanish for $i > 1$, and for there to be an analog of Serre duality.  Maybe $R^1 F$ just ends up being an analog of Cech cohomology?
